# Position dynamically ceated view

Tags: android

```
    Button b1 = new Button(this);
    b1.setText(R.string.hello);
    RelativeLayout layout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.top_menu);
    //android:layout_alignParentRight=true
    layout1.addView(b1);
```

Is there any way to position b1 in layout1? I want it to float right. Or is the only way to replace the complete layout with a new inflated layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [addRule()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule%28int%29) methods to position views in relativeLayout. There are 2 methods, one to position relative to container (RelativeLayout itself. Your case) and another to position relative to other views in the container.

```
Button b1 = new Button(this);
        b1.setText(R.string.hello);
        RelativeLayout layout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.top_menu);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); // Relative layout parameters which specify how the child view will be sized (wrap_content in our case)
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT); // addRule to position it how you need it
        layout1.addView(b1, params);
```

Comment: are these params used for b1 or layout1 ? because It's centered in layout1's parent and not in layout1 itself

Comment: Check your RelativeLayout's width and height. If you have wrap_content for them both, it means that the size of RL will be the same as your b1, so there is no left, or right.